# Dataflow deadlock when first item waits for the second

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a strange deadlock problem with simple dataflow - a transform block and an action block. Transform block should wait on the first item until the second items is entered the action block. Basically I wanted to test that if one item blocks for some external resource then the other items should continue to flow. But it's seems it's not working.

```
[Fact]
public void ProcessAction_FirstWaitsForTheSecond_DataflowEndedOnlyAfterBothProcessed ()
{
    // arrange
    var second_item_finished = new SemaphoreSlim (0, 1);
    var completed_items = new ConcurrentBag<string> ();

    var starting_block = new TransformBlock<string, string>
        (x =>
            {
                if (x == "1")
                    second_item_finished.Wait ();

                return x;
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 100,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            });

    var ending_block = new ActionBlock<string>
        (x =>
            {
                completed_items.Add (x);

                if (x == "2")
                    second_item_finished.Release ();
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                BoundedCapacity = 100,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
            });

    starting_block.LinkTo (ending_block, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });


    // act
    foreach (var data in new[] { "1", "2" })
    {
        if (!starting_block.SendAsync (data).Wait (1000))
            throw new TimeoutException ();
    }

    starting_block.Complete ();

    // timeout here
    if (!Task.WaitAll (new[] { starting_block.Completion, ending_block.Completion }, 1000))
        throw new TimeoutException ();


    // assert
    completed_items.Should ().Equal ("2", "1");
}
```

I'm getting timeout on the "WaitAll" line.

Comment: The problem is in the test, not Dataflow. The semaphore and the multiple `Wait` calls essentially block everything and create an incomprehensilbe web of locks (ie I won't even try to guess what's wrong). If you want to test what happens if only one item runs slowily, add an `if` in the TransformBlock with eg a `Task.Delay or even a Thread.Sleep. If you want to see what is going on, add Console.WriteLine calls or logging. Add a timestamp to each DTO as it passes from one step to another, if you want specific timings.

Comment: I'm not blocking everything. I'm blocking processing of one item. If we have true parallel processing another item will flow to the final block and unblock the first one.

Comment: You aren't blocking one item - you are locking a semaphore used by all items, block sending of individual messages, and finally block awaiting completion of all blocks. This contrived example isn't going to show whether anything runs in parallel or not. If you want to actually *see* the parallel trheads, just put a breakpoint somewhere and check the `Parallel Stacks` debug window. Or simply pause execution and check `Parallel Stacks` after 2 seconds

Comment: I'm blocking one item - the one that equals to "1"